# how to make a boolean hole only get bigger and not fill back in when the object moves away

Tags: modifiers

I don't know how to ask this but basically if I have a rod that is animated to move. The cube that has the boolean would be carved or the hole the rod makes wouldn't be filled in when it moves so it results in a hole in the path of the rod.

this is such a bad way to of explaining it but basically, a lightsaber cutting a door

Comment: I don’t know what to tell you aside from Dynamic Paint. I think you could create a version of the door with the cut in it, and also some mesh to cover the cut: Basically, the part of the door that *was* there. Then, use Dynamic Paint to make the lightsaber paint the cover transparent. I can probably test this. I suspect the tricky part would be getting the cut in the right place for the animation…

Comment: PS: Watch this question https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/252645/73575 If it gets an answer, you might could use that as the hidden source of a Boolean.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, but it is not the cleanest. I did it with geometry nodes, but it is a bit "laggy". You can probably also do it using only modifiers (maybe by making an array on curve that you can than use with boolean)
[image: example how it works]

[[image: nodes2]

So essentially we start by making a cylinder and besier curve (shift + A) this will be the path which the cylinder will follow. With "object info node" we can get the geometry of the curve and cylinder, then we transform the curve to mesh and mesh to points this gives us points evenly spaced on the curve. With the "instance on point node" we replace first "x" points with the cylinder and then use boolean to cut the shape out of the main object. The second "instance on point node" gives us the current location of the cylinder, we pass it to join geometry so we can se it in the output. If you want the cylinder to take smaller steps add a "resample curve node" between "object info node" and "curve to mesh node". I would also advise that you split the mesh you are gona be cutting (in my example the cube) in to different objects. Because every time the "light saber" moves it has to recalculate all previous cuts.

Answer (score -1):

Aply Boolean modifyer. After that, you'll have both the object with a hole, and "rod" for animation.[pict1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRT0L.png)

[image]

Comment: That doesn’t really work for animation. Now we have a permanent hole in the door.

Comment: That would not leave a cut behind the blade on its own.