# adding geometry with geometry nodes over time e.g. a sphere moving in a circle -> torus

Tags: geometry-nodes

I would like to add geometry over time by another moving(animated) geometry.

e.g. I move a sphere in a circle and so i will get  on frame 1 a sphere, on frame 5 some egg-like mesh and on end frame a torus.

More complicated example:
I have suzanne moving on any animated keyframe path. As i think about it...i only need the animated location points as a curve...then i am done... ;)

Should be possible but my brain refuses working right now... :(

Comment: No real idea yet, just trying to come up with a general idea in bullet points: 1. you have the movement on the circle as progress in percent or whatever, something to draw a value from? 2. Are those objects to appear in a collection? 3. Somehow combine the index of those collection objects with the progress...? 4. Or maybe moving the sphere along the points of the circle and combine those points with the collections indices? Sorry, very raw but you are more experienced in GN than me.

Comment: i hoped it would be possible somehow with the new field at index node. And of course i want a "general" solution, not just a torus ;) So i need something like "give me the geometry of that object at frame 72" or as "end goal": give me the joined mesh of suzanne moving from frame 10 to 20.

Comment: The "movement" are just animations...so no, i have no percentage value :(

Comment: Nice way to do this - extract line segment convert to mesh using circle and add two spheres at the ends of the line

Comment: i am sorry if my question wasn't clear. I meant by another moving geometry (animated) and this animation isn't a circle (just for the purpose of simplicity) but any movement in 3d space...that's why i wrote (e.g.) sorry for misunderstandings

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?
[image: example of how it works]

You start by creating a curve around which you build a cylinder and at the end of curve you place a sphere of the same size. If you want a torus just start with a circular curve. Also if you want the steps to be smaller just increase the resample value.[image: node image]